# post value through ajax of uploaded file in php

Tags: php, ajax

We are trying to POST one data string through AJAX here is how it looks

```
// if CAPTCHA is correctly entered!                       
    if ($resp->is_valid) {  echo $tmpName; ?> 


                      <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

   alert("in ready");
        var name = "<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>";

        var email = "<?php echo $_POST['email']; ?>";
        var state = "<?php echo $_POST['state']; ?>";
        var contact = "<?php echo $_POST['phone']; ?>";
         var message = "<?php echo strtr($_POST['message'], array("\r\n" => '<br />', "\r" => '<br />', "\n" => '<br />')); ?>";


        // Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
       var dataString = 'name1='+ name + '&email1='+ email + '&state1='+ state + '&contact1='+ contact + '&message1='+ message +'&tmpName1='+ "<?php echo $tmpName ?>" +'&fileType1='+ "<?php echo $fileType ?>" +'&fileName1='+ "<?php echo $fileName ?>"; 


       alert(dataString);

        if(name==''||email==''||contact=='')
        {
            alert("Please Fill All Fields");
        }
        else
        {
        // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "mailer.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;

});
```

When we are trying to get the value of the tmpName1 but we can not get it but rest like name1 we can get that value. Anyone can suggest on this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Where do you set `name` variable. Please show the relevant HTML code also.

Comment: <?php echo $tmpName; ?> adding a semicolomn after print varName is never wrong

Comment: Aside from my answer like @MarcoMura says you probably should have `;` after each `echo` statement. That may make your PHP code wrong and not execute. Keep in mind that you should have those values on your server side if you are going to be using them on the client side. That means if they aren't correctly declared before the JavaScript gets to the page then it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a different approach for naming the values.

```
var dvals = {};

dvals = {
    name1: name,
    email1: email,
    ...
};
```

Personally I don't do that and I'm not 100% sure why, but I do know that I use in my code.

```
var dvals = {};
dvals['name1'] = name;
dvals['email1'] = email
...
```

You can use that to name each one for sure and then replace `dataString` in your AJAX code with dvals. I am not sure why your `dataString` would be incorrect, but I do know I stopped using it because of random problems I kept running into that made me feel it was unreliable. That is why I switched to using the methods above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get it as you posted it - meaning if you write it like this:

```
dataString = {name_1:name, course_1:course},
```

then you must retrieve it using the names you've given: `name_1` and `course_1`, otherwise it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

this is the right way:

```
var dataString = 'name1='+ name + '&email1='+ email + '&state1='+ state + '&contact1='+ contact + '&message1='+ message +'&tmpName1=<?php echo $tmpName ?>&fileType1= <?php echo $fileType ?>&fileName1=<?php echo $fileName ?>';
```

but this way is better:

```
var tmpName = '<?php echo $tmpName ?>'||'',
fileType    = '<?php echo $fileType ?>'||'',
fileName    = '<?php echo $fileName ?>'||'';

var params = {
    name1:name,
    email1:email,
    state1:state,
    contact1:contact,
    message1:message,
    tmpName1:tmpName,
    fileType1:fileType,
    fileName1:fileName
}

alert(params);

        if(name==''||email==''||contact=='')
        {
            alert("Please Fill All Fields");
        }
        else
        {
        // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "mailer.php",
                data: params,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result){
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But please check the edited one. It dosent seems to be working.